# Confused about different versions of tensorflow on the same OS

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, version

I need to run some code (https://github.com/gnsrla12/crash_to_not_crash) that uses tensorflow's version <2.0 (I don't know what is exact version). Before I downgraded tensorflow to 1.14 via "pip3 install tensorflow==1.14".
And when I list tensorflow versions via pip3, I have:

```
$ pip3 list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow               1.14.0
tensorflow-datasets      2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator     2.0.0
tensorflow-metadata      0.21.1
tensorflow-probability   0.11.0
```

And even when I run the following line:

```
$ python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```

I have (I don't pay attention on FutureWarnings caused by NumPy's version):

```
1.14.0
```

But when I run some module:

```
$ python3 ./scripts/test_script.py
```

That internally has this:

```
import os, time, random, itertools
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print("tf version is ", tf.__version__)

opt = TestOptions().parse()
opt.batchSize = 128  

gpu_config = tf.ConfigProto(
        device_count = {'GPU': opt.gpu_count}
    )
```

I see:

```
('tf version is ', '2.0.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    gpu_config = tf.ConfigProto(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ConfigProto'
```

But I want to use 1.14 version, but not 2.0.0. So, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow does not like beeing installed and uninstalled in the same environment, which can cause issues like the one you got.

I always recommend to use an environment tool like anaconda, to manage your environments, ergo in your case set up tro environments, one for tf2.0 and one for tf1.14. That way, you always have a working environment, which do their job independently.

I also wrote a blog [article](https://michaeljanz-data.science/further-topics/setup-python-environment-with-anaconda-git-bash-for-deep-learning-2/) about this topic, which might be interesting for you.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that it was the case, but I doubted it. Nice article

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer helped you to solve your issue, please consider to accept it by  clicking the mark on the left of my answer. Thank you